# Linux term with profiles (like an XShell)

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm in stuck - does exists terminal with session profiles like XSHell (for connect to many various servers) in Linux?
There are so many terminals, its reqiure a lot of time for test its all!
Can you help?

Comment: Yes? gnome-terminal, xterm, rxvt and even putty exist. What are you asking?

Comment: i want session-select windows, like this: http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/51000/51396/xshell-2.jpg

Comment: After all, i've stopped on Pac Manager - http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/